How to control multiple objects in unity with socket python communication?
I am trying to control multiple objects in unity with position data comming from python. The position data is read as a csv filein python and then send to unity. The data is being send when I am not mistaken, but unity is not doing anything. Does anyone know why?
Python send code
import socket
import time

host, port = "127.0.0.1", 25001
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) # Allow reuse of the port
sock.connect((host, port))

startPos1 = [0, 0, 0] # Initial position for Cylinder1
startPos2 = [0, 0, 0] # Initial position for Cylinder2

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.5) # Sleep 0.5 sec
        
        # Update positions
        startPos1[0] += 0.1 # Increase x by 0.1 for Cylinder1
        startPos2[1] += 0.1 # Increase y by 0.1 for Cylinder2
        
        # Convert positions to string format expected by Unity
        posString1 = '(' + ','.join(map(str, startPos1)) + ')'
        posString2 = '(' + ','.join(map(str, startPos2)) + ')'
        posString = f"pos1:{posString1};pos2:{posString2}"
        
        print(posString)
        
        # Send position string to Unity
        sock.sendall(posString.encode("UTF-8"))
        
        # Receive and print the response from Unity
        receivedData = sock.recv(1024).decode("UTF-8")
        print(receivedData)
finally:
    sock.close() # Ensure the socket is closed when done


Unity receiving code
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Threading;

public class CSharpForGIT : MonoBehaviour
{
    Thread mThread;
    public string connectionIP = "127.0.0.1";
    public int connectionPort = 25001;
    IPAddress localAdd;
    TcpListener listener;
    TcpClient client;

    public GameObject cylinder1;
    public GameObject cylinder2;

    Vector3 receivedPos1 = Vector3.zero;
    Vector3 receivedPos2 = Vector3.zero;

    private object lockObject = new object();

    bool running;

    private void Update()
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            if (cylinder1 != null)
            {
                cylinder1.transform.position = receivedPos1;
            }

            if (cylinder2 != null)
            {
                cylinder2.transform.position = receivedPos2;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(GetInfo);
        mThread = new Thread(ts);
        mThread.Start();
    }

    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        running = false;
        if (client != null) client.Close();
        if (listener != null) listener.Stop();
        if (mThread != null) mThread.Abort();
    }

    void GetInfo()
    {
        try
        {
            localAdd = IPAddress.Parse(connectionIP);
            listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, connectionPort);
            listener.Start();

            client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

            running = true;
            while (running)
            {
                SendAndReceiveData();
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            Debug.Log("Socket exception: " + ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            listener.Stop();
        }
    }

    void SendAndReceiveData()
    {
        NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];

        int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
        string dataReceived = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataReceived))
        {
            ProcessReceivedData(dataReceived);

            byte[] myWriteBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hey I got your message Python! Do You see this message?");
            nwStream.Write(myWriteBuffer, 0, myWriteBuffer.Length);
        }
    }

    void ProcessReceivedData(string data)
    {
        string[] positions = data.Split(';');
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            foreach (var pos in positions)
            {
                if (pos.StartsWith("pos1:"))
                {
                    receivedPos1 = StringToVector3(pos.Substring(5));
                }
                else if (pos.StartsWith("pos2:"))
                {
                    receivedPos2 = StringToVector3(pos.Substring(5));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static Vector3 StringToVector3(string sVector)
    {
        if (sVector.StartsWith("(") && sVector.EndsWith(")"))
        {
            sVector = sVector.Substring(1, sVector.Length - 2);
        }

        string[] sArray = sVector.Split(',');

        Vector3 result = new Vector3(
            float.Parse(sArray[0]),
            float.Parse(sArray[1]),
            float.Parse(sArray[2]));

        return result;
    }
}


I tried changing the host number because unity gives an error: SocketException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
I feel like with one object its working fine, but i want one script that controls 14 objects, based on an ID later on. So doesnt make sense to split everything in 14 scripts.

Vector3 is not thread-save .. have you tried to use a lock? also you never set receivedPos1 and receivedPos2 ..

I have added a lock. I am sorry for the code, it was a wrong version, I updated the code now to the latest version, including lock. Unfortunately the two objects still dont move.

well have you tried debugging and stepping through your code to see where it stops behaving as expected?

I dont know how to debug it because there is no error so far, apart from the "SocketException: Only one usage of each socket address" within unity. The data is being send from Python and also returned from c# tp Python. Still nothing moves in unity.

and also returned from c# to Python how did you check that?
